# javascript/html flowing tables on to new line

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have some javascript that generates a variable number of tables. Currently, these tables are displayed in a list down the page:

[image]

However, this means that, if there are more than about four tables, the bottom ones are not visible and I need to scroll, meaning I can't see the top ones.

So, what I would like to do is to somehow 'flow' the tables (I can make them narrower) across the page and then on to a new line. So, if I have five tables, then I have (say) two columns on the page, with heats 1, 3 and 5 appearing in column 1; and heats 2 and 4 in column 2.

Here is the section of the code that deals with this:

```
    numGroups = groups.length;
for (var g = 0; g < numGroups; g++)
{

    // Create a new table for each group
    var t=document.createElement('table');


    t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';
    t.style.cellPadding = '5px';

    // Create table header showing group number
    var caption = document.createElement( "caption" );
    caption.style.textAlign = 'left';
    caption.style.paddingTop = '10px';
    caption.style.color = "white";

    
    thisGroup = (g+1);                                                  
    
    caption.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Group "+thisGroup));
    t.appendChild(caption);
    

    var headers = ["Pos", "Driver", "Score", "Best Lap"];
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++)
    {
        var th = document.createElement( "th" );
        th.style.color = headerColour;
        th.style.border= theBorderWidth + borderColour;
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(headers[i]));
        t.appendChild(th);

    }
    
    
    // Create a table record for each driver in the group
    
    numGroupDrivers = groups[g].length
    
    for (var k = 0; k <numGroupDrivers; k++)                                        //run through each of the drivers in the heat.
    {        
        var tr=document.createElement('tr');                                        //create variable 'tr' to create a table row
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        tr.style.color = textColour;    
        
        var name = groups[g][k];                                                    //variable name = nickname
        
        if (name == null && config.d) {                                             //if name isn't blank and this is a digital race...
            continue;
        }

        // Create column for position 
        var tdPos=document.createElement('td');                                     //create variable 'tdPos' to create a table cell with data
        tdPos.style.width='50px';
        tdPos.style.textAlign='center';
        tdPos.style.border=theBorderWidth + borderColour;
        tdPos.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k+1));                                //go through the table in order setting tdPos to row number
        tr.appendChild(tdPos);                                                      //add tdPos to table record
        
            
        var tdName=document.createElement('td');                                    //create variable 'tdName' to create a table cell with data
        tdName.style.width='250px';
        tdName.style.textAlign='center';
        tdName.style.border=theBorderWidth + borderColour;
        tdName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        tr.appendChild(tdName);

            
        //Create column for score
        var tdScore=document.createElement('td');
        tdScore.style.width='80px';
        tdScore.style.textAlign='center';
        tdScore.style.border=theBorderWidth + borderColour;


        for (var l = 0; l <scoreArray.length; l++)
        {
            if (groups[g][k] == scoreArray[l][0])
            {
                if (scoreArray[l] == 0) 
                {
                    tdScore.appendChild(document.createTextNode("--"));
                } else 
                {
                    tdScore.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scoreArray[l][1]));
                }
            }
            tr.appendChild(tdScore);
        
            t.appendChild(tr);
        }

        //Create column for best lap
        var tdTime=document.createElement('td');
        tdTime.style.width='120px';
        tdTime.style.textAlign='center';
        tdTime.style.border=theBorderWidth + borderColour;

        for (var l = 0; l <scoreArray.length; l++)
        {
            if (groups[g][k] == scoreArray[l][0])
            {
                if (scoreArray[l][2] == -1) 
                {
                    tdTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode("--"));
                } else 
                {
                    tdTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scoreArray[l][2]));
                }
            }
            tr.appendChild(tdTime);
        
            t.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }



    groupTables[g] = t;
}
```

Any help gratefully received!

Thanks,

Connal

Comment: You might set `width: 45%; display: inline-table` to your tables.

Comment: hi - could you be more specific please? I tried this but it didn't make any difference. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question.

In spirit, though, I think it's the best answer you'll get...

*Learn css-flex.* JavaScript as presentational layer will be brittle and is not the optimal place for it anyway. On a large screen and mouse (i.e. a laptop or desktop but not a phone) take a look at [MDN's tutorial on flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). You'll be able to get what you want in a way that

- degrades nicely,
- is faster,
- is less reliant on platform/browser,
- already debugged,
- helps you learn another browser-native technology that you'll have on your tool belt tomorrow
- might possibly be more accessible to screen readers and other aids for the visually impaired,
- flows better, and smoothly, when someone resizes their screen or changes the font size.

Bonus: Anyone in the future maintaining your code (including and especially youself) will find it much easier.

I had resisted learning flex for years, choosing instead to keep moving with my then-current projects as fast as I could. I regret that. I'm screwed; I'll never get that time back. My best way to pay it forward is to highly recommend you give it a shot.

If anyone has another great link for intro to CSS flex that they recommend, please comment.

So, if you adopt this approach, then instead of a TABLE tag contains TR tags containing TD tags, you'll need to generate a DIV (or SECTION) tag that has a specific class attribute, containing a DIV (or ARTICLE) tag per "row", which contain DIV tags per "cell", and after that it's all CSS.

If you're still not convinced, try looking at [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) for examples of how, if you organize your HTML to tell the browser only "what the information is" and leave "what it should look like" to CSS, both tasks are easier to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the advice but I need to get this done before the weekend and it is probably the only time I am going to need it, so I don't want to spend too much time figuring it out. I'm sure you are right, though.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, You might set `width: 45%; display: inline-table` to your tables:

```js
var groups = [
    ['John', 'Sam', 'Peter'],
    ['John', 'Sam', 'Peter'],
    ['John', 'Sam', 'Peter'],
    ['John', 'Sam', 'Peter'],
    ['John', 'Sam', 'Peter'],
  ],
  scoreArray = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ],
  g = 0,
  headerColour = 'gold',
  textColour = 'black',
  borderColour = 'black',
  theBorderWidth = 'solid 1px ';

groups.forEach(idx => {

  // Create a new table for each group
  var t = document.createElement('table');

  t.style.width = '45%';
  t.style.display = 'inline-table';
  t.style.marginRight = '2%';

  t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';
  t.style.cellPadding = '5px';

  // Create table header showing group number
  var caption = document.createElement("caption");
  caption.style.textAlign = 'left';
  caption.style.paddingTop = '10px';
  caption.style.color = "white";


  thisGroup = (g + 1);

  caption.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Group " + thisGroup));
  t.appendChild(caption);


  var headers = ["Pos", "Driver", "Score", "Best Lap"];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.style.color = headerColour;
    th.style.border = theBorderWidth + borderColour;
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(headers[i]));
    t.appendChild(th);

  }


  // Create a table record for each driver in the group

  numGroupDrivers = groups[g].length

  for (var k = 0; k < numGroupDrivers; k++) //run through each of the drivers in the heat.
  {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr'); //create variable 'tr' to create a table row
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    tr.style.color = textColour;

    var name = groups[g][k]; //variable name = nickname

    if (name == null && config.d) { //if name isn't blank and this is a digital race...
      continue;
    }

    // Create column for position 
    var tdPos = document.createElement('td'); //create variable 'tdPos' to create a table cell with data
    tdPos.style.width = '50px';
    tdPos.style.textAlign = 'center';
    tdPos.style.border = theBorderWidth + borderColour;
    tdPos.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k + 1)); //go through the table in order setting tdPos to row number
    tr.appendChild(tdPos); //add tdPos to table record


    var tdName = document.createElement('td'); //create variable 'tdName' to create a table cell with data
    tdName.style.width = '250px';
    tdName.style.textAlign = 'center';
    tdName.style.border = theBorderWidth + borderColour;
    tdName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    tr.appendChild(tdName);


    //Create column for score
    var tdScore = document.createElement('td');
    tdScore.style.width = '80px';
    tdScore.style.textAlign = 'center';
    tdScore.style.border = theBorderWidth + borderColour;


    for (var l = 0; l < scoreArray.length; l++) {
      if (groups[g][k] == scoreArray[l][0]) {
        if (scoreArray[l] == 0) {
          tdScore.appendChild(document.createTextNode("--"));
        } else {
          tdScore.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scoreArray[l][1]));
        }
      }
      tr.appendChild(tdScore);

      t.appendChild(tr);
    }

    //Create column for best lap
    var tdTime = document.createElement('td');
    tdTime.style.width = '120px';
    tdTime.style.textAlign = 'center';
    tdTime.style.border = theBorderWidth + borderColour;

    for (var l = 0; l < scoreArray.length; l++) {
      if (groups[g][k] == scoreArray[l][0]) {
        if (scoreArray[l][2] == -1) {
          tdTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode("--"));
        } else {
          tdTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scoreArray[l][2]));
        }
      }
      tr.appendChild(tdTime);

      t.appendChild(tr);
    }
  }



  document.body.appendChild(t);
})
```

Comment: Just tried this and it works! Many thanks

Comment: @ConnalMcIlwraith, appreciate your feedback =))

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS with an external stylesheet and/or a `<style>` tag at the bottom of the `<head>`. You can unclutter the JavaScript by removing all of the expressions with the `.style` property. Use `.class` to apply CSS styles to the tags. In the example below, are 7 tables. When there are 5 or less tables, they have `width: 100%`. When there are more than 5 tables all tables are given the `.half` class which decreases their widths to 50%. The following styles will automatically arrange the tables in 2 columns when they have class `.half`:

```
main { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;...}
/* Flexbox properties will arrange the tables in two columns when 
there are more than 5 of them (because .half will be added to
each table */
.half { width: 50%; }
```

This flow control statement is responsible for the class change:

```
if (qty > 5) {
  tables.forEach(t => t.classList.add('half'));
} else {
  tables.forEach(t => t.classList.remove('half'));
}
```

Also, it's important that you have full control of the tables, in the example, it `fetch()`es data from a test server to create as many tables as the `qty` parameter dictates (in example, it's `heats = 7`). Normally table column widths are determined by content which makes them sporadically unseemly (especially with dynamic content). `table-layout: fixed` allows you to set the widths of the columns by adding explicit widths directly to the `<th>` (or the top `<td>` if `<th>` are not present):

```
table { table-layout: fixed; ...}
```

BTW, the `Total Time` does not coincide with `Position` (ie. lowest `Total Time` should be matched with `Position: 1`). If you want to sort the columns you'll need to start another question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>NASCAR HEAT</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
    *, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
    :root { font: 1ch/1 'Segoe UI'; }
    html, body { width: 100%; min-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body { font-size: 2ch; color: white; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #85a4e5 13%,#053cbd 66%); }
    main { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
    table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid white; }
    caption { font-size: 1.35rem; font-weight: 900; text-align: left; }
    th, td { border: 1px solid white; text-align: center; }
    th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2) { text-align: left; }
    th { font-size: 1.25rem; overflow: hidden; }
    td { font-size: 1.15rem; }
    th:first-of-type { width: 5%; }
    th:nth-of-type(2) { width: 55%; }
    th:nth-of-type(3) { width: 15%; }
    th:nth-of-type(4) { width: 15%; }
    th:last-of-type { width: 15%; }
    .half { width: 50%; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main></main>
  <script>
    let heats = 7;

    function buildTables(selector, qty = 1) {
      const headers = ['Position', 'Driver', 'Average Lap', 'Best Lap', 'Total Time'];
      const base = document.querySelector(selector) || document.body;

      for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        let t = document.createElement('table');
        let tB = document.createElement('tbody');
        let cap = t.createCaption();
        cap.textContent = `Heat ${i + 1}`;
        t.append(tB);
        let tH = t.createTHead();
        let hRow = tH.insertRow();
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          hRow.insertCell().outerHTML = `<th>${headers[j]}</th>`;
        }
        base.append(t);
      }
      const tables = [...document.querySelectorAll('table')];

      for (let k = 0; k < qty; k++) {
        fetch('https://my.api.mockaroo.com/nascar.json?key=3634fcf0').then((res) => res.json()).then(res => {
          let row;
          for (let r in res) {
            row = `<tr>
    <td>${res[r].Position}</td>
    <td>${res[r].Driver}</td>
    <td>${res[r]['Average Lap']}</td>
    <td>${res[r]['Best Lap']}</td>
    <td>${res[r]['Total Time']}</td>
    </tr>`;
            tables[k].tBodies[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
          }
        });
      }
      if (qty > 5) {
        tables.forEach(t => t.classList.add('half'));
      } else {
        tables.forEach(t => t.classList.remove('half'));
      }
    };

    buildTables('main', heats);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have a go.